# how to get objects from array of pointer using parse in Android?

Tags: android, parsing, callback, cloud

Database Relationship

there is a group 
`DYNAMICGROUPS` -> having array of pointers column(members) -> that contains `array of user's objectId`. Now I want to apply query in `DYNAMICGROUPS` to get all the details of `dynamicGroups` and all the object details of individual pointers of members column. Right now I am doing from multiple queries but its creating issue : [Synchronous issue code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418383/how-to-run-code-sequentially-with-parse-in-android/31418907#31418907)

```
final ArrayList<TempGroupClass> tempGroupList = new ArrayList<TempGroupClass>();
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("username",
            SharedPreferencesClass.getUserName(context));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> arg0, ParseException arg1) {
            if (arg1 == null) {
                if(arg0.size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getUpdatedRecordsFromParse");
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("DynamicGroup");
                ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
                array.add(arg0.get(0).getObjectId());
                query.whereContainedIn("members", array);
                query.include("code");
                query.include("members");
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> arg0, ParseException arg1) {
                        if (arg1 == null) {
                            if (arg0.size() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < arg0.size(); i++) {
                                    TempGroupClass temp = new TempGroupClass();
                                    ArrayList<String>   friendListArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                                    **<!-- arg0.get(i).getList("members")   this is giving me array of pointers now  i want object details of every pointer but how ? -->**
                                    // now to get dynamic group members array
                                    // loop through every member and
                                    for (int j = 0; j < arg0.get(i).getList("members").size(); j++) {
                                        // here we are excluding our object id from members id recieved from parse
                                        if (!(SharedPreferencesClass.getUserObjectId(context)
                                            .equalsIgnoreCase(arg0.get(i).getList("members").get(j).toString()))) {
                                            // friendarraylist excluding our objectID
                                            friendListArray.add(arg0.get(i).getList("members").get(j).toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                    temp.setParseObjectId(arg0.get(i).getObjectId());
                                    temp.setFriendObjectIdList(friendListArray);
                                    // now get information of groups from groupCode
                                    Log.d(TAG,"setFriendObjectIdList size:" + temp.getFriendObjectIdList().size());

                                    /****************now get  group code information start *******************/
                                    ParseObject objectCodeObj = new ParseObject("DynamicGroup");
                                    objectCodeObj = arg0.get(i).getParseObject("code");
                                    String groupTitle = objectCodeObj.getString("code");
                                    // Pointor Object value                                     Log.d(TAG,"GROUP CODE STRING  :" + groupTitle);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "GROUP CODE EXPIRES TIME :" + objectCodeObj.getDate("expires"));
                                    /*****now get  group code information stop ***********/
                                    // loop for testing purpose what we r getting in list
                                    for(int j = 0; j < temp.getFriendObjectIdList().size(); j++) {
                                        Log.d(TAG,"member id:"+temp.getFriendObjectIdList().get(j));
                                    }
                                    temp.setGroupTitle(groupTitle);
                                    temp.setExpires(objectCodeObj.getDate("expires"));
                                        tempGroupList.add(temp);
                                }
                                getRecords(tempGroupList);
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "DynamicGroup arg0.size else :" + arg0.size());
                            }
                        }
                        // Log.d(TAG,"returned Group List size 1:" + tempGroupList.size());
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,"user arg0.size:"+arg0.size());   
            }
        }
    }
});
```

if I'm doing like above method then I'm also getting issues in my next query so how should I write my query and get all object details at once and then save in local/temp `ArrayList()` ?

**Table Structure :**

DynamicGroup
[image: DynamicGroup]

GroupCode
[image: GroupCode]

User Table
[image: user table]

Comment: As a warning, do not spam comments across the site asking people to answer your question. I just removed all of these after many of them were flagged. That's not a proper use of comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your "members" column is not an array of Pointers, it's an array of string object id's.  If you had actually set them up as pointers, this is a trivial single query with one `include('members')` constraint.

When saving objects to an array column, don't save the object id, save the whole object... it will be converted to a pointer.

You can manually edit your array, for example, changing:

```
["iHHyf1Rerw", "sFqTz7FHCJ", "fxZ0GXOtrn"]
```

to:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"iHHyf1Rerw"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"sFqTz7FHCJ"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"fxZ0GXOtrn"}]
```

If you have a large amount of data already misconfigured like this, you could use an adhoc background job to update all of them.

Comment: but my question is how will i pass json to save this data  ? from android @Fosco

Comment: I saved the whole PFUSer but on Parses website, it shows the text as you have it and not a clickable user pointer. Why is that? Do I need to define my column as being a pointer or leave it as an Array?

Comment: If it's an array column, it'll never be clickable, but it's still valid... Only pointer column types (pointing to one object) will be clickable to see the pointed-to object.

Answer (score 0):

I think what @Fosco said about json is if you want to insert MANUALLY.
From your code you should save to array the hole objects, not their id's.